# Perform GC.Collect on another process

Tags: c#

I have an application that creates new processes in runtime and inside these processes AppDomains.

To monitor the survived memory of an AppDomain I need to first perform a GC.Collect, but when in another process I don't know exactly how to do it. Is there a way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there is a more direct way, but here is one that clearly works: Make the other app expose some RPC endpoint that you can call to initiate a GC. For example, use .NET Remoting to open a very simple named pipe connected service. The code to do that is surprisingly small.

Comment: That is what I'm thinking about doing. Just asking because I don't know if there is a more declarative way to do it, since tools like dotMemory can force a GC without the need to have an explicit endpoint.

Comment: These tools use the CLR profiler API which is extremely invasive and requires being attached when the process starts AFAIK.

Comment: Makes sense... Thanks!

Comment: Another way would be to load a .NET library into that process remotely, then to create a remote thread running code in that library. Then, you can simply call GC.Collect from that loaded library. Non-trivial technique.

Comment: In fact, I would like a more "lightly" way to monitor the RAM usage on an AppDomain... 

I was thinking about polling the information in the  AppDomain.MonitoringSurvivedMemorySize, but the documentation says that, to get the accurate statistic, a full, blocking collection needs to be performed immediately before getting the property value. To build something like a watchdog that will keep a close eye to this information, and then take action when needed, I don't like the idea of performing a GC.Collect(), let's say, every 10 seconds.

(and this is enough doubt for another question, though)

Comment: Why don't you monitor private bytes? That's the relevant value from other applications perspectives. Also you could record ETW events. PerfView uses ETW to trace amazing GC statistics with all kinds of memory size information. ETW is not invasive at all.

Comment: but how is it possible to grab the private bytes for a specific AppDomain? It's third-party plugins that I don't want to harm the whole system, so the app performing the monitoring is the app that creates the AppDomains.

Also, do you know some place I can read about how to use ETW in code?

Comment: I see, no private bytes then. Maybe run each plugin appdomain in its own process.

Comment: Yes, I guess it's the only way to achieve what I want the wat I want... thanks a lot for the talk!